# Bash problems with nginx start command

Tags: bash, shell, nginx, scripting, ksh

I have two scripts:

**nginx_1.sh:**

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service nginx start
```

and

nginx_2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service nginx start
```

After running the first script (*nginx_1.sh*) I get the following output (nginx is up and running):

> `Stopping nginx:                                            [  OK  ]`
>
> `Starting nginx:                                            [  OK  ]`

When I start nginx again, and run the second script (*nginx_2.sh*) I only get the:

> `Stopping nginx:                                            [  OK  ]`

No start command is issued. I did `ps` but no nginx was there.

If I remove `#!/bin/bash` or change it to `#!/bin/ksh` *nginx_2.sh* works fine. Why?

Comment: *How* do you run the scripts?

Comment: ./nginx_1.sh
./nginx_2.sh

Comment: Run again using `bash -x nginx_2.sh`, that should trace the code.  With such simple scripts there shouldn't be any difference between bash and ksh.  Most likely you are starting the service when it hasn't shut down.  Try inserting a `sleep 2` (or something) between the two calls.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but this should work for you: `sudo service nginx restart`.

Comment: cdarke: I wrote taht I started nginx again and truied with the second code and checked the PS - does not work :) dont know why

pgl: stop - works, restart - works, reload - works, start - does not work. I want to know why :)